# How to get TypeScript to strongly type a function argument where the keys come from the parent class

Tags: typescript

I have a rather unusual requirement which I'd like to model with TypeScript types.

Consider the following example.  I have a function called `create_object_a`, and the input is an object, however the values for the object are another object which has the *same* keys as the parent object:

*EDIT: I made a mistake, this example does not give the type error which I thought it did, so neither this nor the follow example work.  However @jcalz provided an answer to my question which fixes both.*

```js
type KeysToObject<U extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [P in keyof U]: string;
};

function create_object_a<U extends Record<string, KeysToObject<U>>>(input: U) {}

create_object_a({
  abc: {
    // No error:
    abc: "hi"

    // Type error since the parent class has no "xyz" field:
    xyz: "hi"
  }
});
```

This actually works suprisingly well - everything is strongly typed and VS Code Intellisense suggests the fields correct.

Now consider this very similar situation, but where I want the object values to be **a function which takes an object as an argument, which has the same keys as the parent**:

```js
// Note that the second parameter to Record is the thing that's changed 
// compared to the previous example
function create_object_b<U extends Record<string, (x: KeysToObject<U>) => any>>(input: U) {}

create_object_b({
  abc: (x) => {
    // No error:
    x.abc = "hello";

    // SHOULD BE A TYPE ERROR BUT ISN'T:
    x.xyx = "hello";
  }
});
```

Why is TypeScript not able to strongly type this function argument, when in the previous example it could, and is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I'm confused. In your second example, why is `x.abc` not an error? Why is `x.xyx` specifically a *type error*?

Comment: There are a number of seeming misconceptions here so I'm not sure how to answer "why is TypeScript not able to strongly type this function argument, when in the previous example it could".  A major one is that `{abc: "hi", xyz: "hi"}` is a perfectly acceptable instance of `{abc: string}`, so what you're looking for isn't "strong typing" but *excess property warnings*, and excess property warnings only happen in specific circumstances.  If your primary question is "how can I make this work" then I'd suggest [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nleqlm), if it meets your use cases.  Does it?

Comment: If so then I'll write up an answer explaining the solution, but I don't know how much I should go into why your version doesn't work.  If not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz in your reply if you want me to be notified)

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, I messed up slightly - VS Code was underlining the `xyz` field and I assumed it was a type error, when it was actually because I forgot the comma!  So that was my mistake, and you can ignore than part of the question.  However you interpreted my actual question correctly and the solution you gave is exactly what I hoped for, so thank you.  If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it.